# Where is the alarm siren located in a Ford Ka 2010?

Tags: ford, alarm, ka

I have a Ford Ka 2010 and the alarm siren stopped sounding. The problem doesn't  look related to the alarm central unit. The lights still flash and you can hear the relay clicking sound coming from the central panel when the alarm goes off, but no sound is heard from the alarm siren. If knew where it is located and what it look like it would be of great help! Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: Does the horn still work? Most factory installed alarm systems work through the horn system ... you may want to check it to see if it's still viable.

Comment: The horn does work, but you can see the alarm uses something else - when it used to work the sound which came from it was kind of a "beep", completely different from the sound of the horn, which is even louder. That's why I'm looking for the siren... but if I don't find it in the end I think of intercepting the wire coming from the alarm central to the lateral lights - they used to flash along with the siren when the alarm goes off - so I can sound the horn instead with the same 12V used to flash the lights.